# Iterate two lists in the same loop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, time

How do I iterate through two lists in Python? I want exactly the result of

```
list1, list2, list3 = [0, 1], ['a', 'b'], [2, 3] # example data

for item in list1 + list2 + list3:
    print(item)
```

But I think adding lists and then iterating through them is not efficient. I used `for` loop to iterate through the lists:

```
for list_ in (list1, list2, list3):
    for item in list_:
        print(item)
```

But when I checked this with `timeit` execution time of both was very similar.

Is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For small data sets you will not find much difference. But normally if you want to chain and iterate multiple iterables, then you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), like this

```
>>> list1, list2, list3 = [0, 1], ['a', 'b'], [2, 3]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for item in chain(list1, list2, list3):
...     print(item)
0
1
a
b
2
3
```

This doesn't create any intermediate data structures and iterate each of the iterables one by one. The value returned by `chain` is an iterator. So that also doesn't create a container with all the items in it and it is very memory efficient if the iterables are going to be very big.

And `itertools.chain` is effectively the same as your second approach. Quoting the equivalent implementation from the official docs

```
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```

---

If we look at the byte code generated for the first program you have shown, with this

```
from dis import dis
list1, list2, list3 = [0, 1], ['a', 'b'], [2, 3]


def func():
    for item in list1 + list2 + list3:
        print(item)

dis(func)
```

it would be something like

```
  6           0 SETUP_LOOP              27 (to 30)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list1)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list2)
              9 BINARY_ADD          
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (list3)
             13 BINARY_ADD          
             14 GET_ITER            
        >>   15 FOR_ITER                11 (to 29)
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (item)

  7          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             24 PRINT_ITEM          
             25 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15
        >>   29 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `BINARY_ADD` code is used twice. It means that `list1` and `list2` are added first and a temporary list is created and that is again added with `list3`. This will be highly inefficient if any of the lists is very big.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
for item in itertools.chain(list1, list2, list2):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from `itertools` module to chain the three lists into single one:

```
from itertools import chain:

for item in chain(list1, list2, list3):
    print(item)
```

OR:

```
for item in chain.from_iterable([list1,list2,list3]):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're more of a numbers person, here is a test case providing evidence that it is inefficient to add the lists together before iterating through.

Note that `hugelists.py` contains three lists each containing 10,000 random four-digit numbers.

```
from hugelists import list_one, list_two, list_three
from itertools import chain
from datetime import datetime

def method_one():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    for item in list_one + list_two + list_three:
        pass
    stop_time = datetime.now()
    return stop_time - start_time

def method_two():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    for item in chain(list_one, list_two, list_three):
        pass
    stop_time = datetime.now()
    return stop_time - start_time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print method_one()
    print method_two()
```

Results:

```
> python test.py
0:00:00.001720
0:00:00.001014
> python test.py
0:00:00.001865
0:00:00.000997
> python test.py
0:00:00.001603
0:00:00.000833
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the builtin [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
>>> for m, n, k in zip([1,2,3,4,5], list('abcde'), [2,11,25,102,53]):
        print(m, n, k)


1 a 2
2 b 11
3 c 25
4 d 102
5 e 53
```

Notice you can put other iterables into it.

```
for m, n, k in zip(range(1,6), 'abcde', [2,11,25,102,53]):
    print(m, n, k)


1 a 2
2 b 11
3 c 25
4 d 102
5 e 53
```